# Using preg_replace for a-z A-Z 0-9 and Slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using regex for replacing everything but a-z A-Z 0-9. I'll like to add that its not removing Slash ( / ) but anyhow it wont work. I dont found the error.

thx for your help!

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', '/[ -]+/', '/^-|-$/'), array('', '-', ''), $string);
```

Comment: Did you properly escaped it? Since you use the slash also as regex delimiter.

Comment: Reading the regex: "Not a to z A to Z 0 to 9 to ???"

Comment: Actually, this one is without the Slash. But its working great, its killing all special chars but not regular chars. I need an example with the added Slash holding

Comment: You want to allow slash as well? `[^a-zA-Z0-9/-]` then change your delimiter, or `[^a-zA-Z0-9\/-]`.

Comment: @apokryfos `Not a to z A to Z 0 to 9 not hyphen`.

Comment: @apokryfos see [Explanation box](https://regex101.com/r/cW2gN0/1) on the right panel

Comment: I'd like to point out that `\w` is short for `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, and `\W` is short for `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: @SWLim `\w` includes underscore; as does the inverse `\W`.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out! Didn't actually notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to escape forward slash. I'd try `[^-a-z0-9\/]+` to search and replace all unwanted characters.

```
$re = "/[^-a-z0-9\\/]+/i"; 
$str = "asdkf\n43435&\$*k((/\\"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

This will reduce string **`asdkf\n43435&\$*k((/\\`** to **`asdkf43435k/`**

See demo https://regex101.com/r/vY2jC7/1

**Fix**:
I forgot to add `i` modifier to ignore case as pointed out by @chris85 which will lead to ignoring upper case letters.

See Updated demo at See demo https://regex101.com/r/vY2jC7/2

Comment: There's no `i` modifier so all capital letters will also be removed. I don't think that is the intent of OP.

Comment: Thank you, i dont minded to place a double backslash... works great now

Comment: Using `$re = '~[^-a-z0-9/]+~i';` would be cleaner.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agreed. Just copied generated code from regex101 and I'm sure can be further optimized.